# How to read files from a folder and its subfolder and write into a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I want to read file names from a folder and its subfolders and want to create new file `mainfest.JSON` which will have a list of all file names.

Here  is the Requirement

```
**Input:**

\Temp\file1.txt
\Temp\file2.log
\Temp\subTemp\file3.txt
\Temp\subTemp\file4.txt

**Output**
Mainefest.json
[
“file1.txt” : “\Temp\file1.txt”,
“file2.log” : “\Temp\file2.log”,
“file3.txt” : “\Temp\ subTemp \file1.txt”,
“file4.txt” : “\Temp\ subTemp \file1.txt”
]
```

below is my sample code

```
gulp.task('TestApp', function(){
    return gulp.src('./Temp/**/*.*')
        .pipe(
            hash({
                algorithm: 'md5',
                hashLength: 20
            })) // Add hashes to the files' names
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./Output')) // Write the renamed files
            .pipe(hash.manifest('mainfest.json', {
            deleteOld: true,
            sourceDir: __dirname + './output'
        })) // Switch to the manifest file

});
```

It works well. but it add hashes, which i do not want .

I am allowed to use javascript,gulp, node js.
Is there anyone who can help me to achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the part that adds the hashes according to the comment in the code example (` // Add hashes to the files names`)?

Comment: `It works well. but it add hashes, which i do not want .` why did you add the hash part then?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work fine:

```
const   path=require('path'),
        fs=require('fs');

class Parser{
    constructor(dir,out){
        this.dir=dir;
        this.out=out;
    }
    parse(){
        const res=[];
        this._parse(this.dir,res);
        fs.writeFileSync(this.out,JSON.stringify(res));
    }
    _parse(dir,result){
        for(const entry of fs.readdirSync(dir)){
            if(fs.lstatSync(path.join(dir,entry)).isDirectory()){
                this._parse(path.join(dir,entry),result);
            }else{
                const e={};
                e[entry]=path.join(dir,entry)
                result.push(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
module.exports=Parser;
```

You can use it like this:

```
const parser=require('path/to/file/contains/class'),
      Parser=new parser('dir/to/read','path/to/output/file.json');
Parser.parse();
```